# R mxnet random initialization

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks, predictive-models, weights

Is there a way to create an mxnet neural network with randomly initialized weights without training the network? Most user manuals that I surely read include only two parts: symbolic network creation, and training (which includes weight initialization). How can one create and initialize a network for the purpose of generating randomized predictions?

Comment: https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/model.html#initializer-api-reference Edit: sorry that's the python reference and your question is for R.  However this also work in R. Will find ref later

Comment: Are you just asking about the R functions / how to do this in R, or are you asking about mxnet NNs generally & a software-neutral answer would be just as good? (Note that the former is off topic here.)

Comment: Having an answer related to the R implementation of mxnet framework would be ideal, but referring to a similar code in Python would work as well, given that R version has the same functionality. I need exactly to learn how to create **model** that is not trained, which I can use as follows: preds = predict(**model**, test.x). I do not want to do: **model** <- mx.model.FeedForward.create(......) - which is a training logic.

Comment: If you have a statistical reason for investigating random weights I think it would be interesting to add that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use mx.model.init.params.  Here is a demo based on the R example from the MXNet.  Note that the underlying model that you call predict on is most easily created in the normal way, you can just overwrite the parameters afterwards- that's what the code below does.  It then plots the trained predictions against the random ones.  Feel free to change the seed or use mx.init.normal etc to check the new parameters are actually used for predictions!  (Aside: if anyone knows a clean function to get the input shape feel free to edit the answer!)

```
library(mxnet)
library(mlbench)

data(BostonHousing, package="mlbench")

train.ind = seq(1, 506, 3)
train.x = data.matrix(BostonHousing[train.ind, -14])
train.y = BostonHousing[train.ind, 14]
test.x = data.matrix(BostonHousing[-train.ind, -14])
test.y = BostonHousing[-train.ind, 14]


# Define the input data
data <- mx.symbol.Variable("data")

# A fully connected hidden layer
# data: input source
# num_hidden: number of neurons in this hidden layer
fc1 <- mx.symbol.FullyConnected(data, num_hidden=1)

# Use linear regression for the output layer
lro <- mx.symbol.LinearRegressionOutput(fc1)

# View network
graph.viz(lro)

# Trained network model
mx.set.seed(0)
model <- mx.model.FeedForward.create(lro, X=train.x, y=train.y,
                                     ctx=mx.cpu(),     num.round=10, array.batch.size=20,
                                     learning.rate=2e-6, eval.metric=mx.metric.rmse)

# trained parameters
model$arg.params

# predictions on test sample
trained_pred <- predict(model, test.x)


# Get input shape
# (This is used to describe the network/input data)
get.input.shape <- function(X, y) {
  X<-t(X) # assumes X is in rowmajor format
  X <- mxnet:::mx.model.init.iter(X, y, batch.size=20, is.train=TRUE)

  if (!X$iter.next()) {
    X$reset()
    if (!X$iter.next()) stop("Empty input")
  }
  sapply("data", function(n){dim(X$value()[[n]])}, simplify = FALSE) 
}

input.shape = get.input.shape(train.x,train.y) 

initializer <- mx.init.uniform(0.01)

mx.set.seed(2)
model$arg.params <- mx.model.init.params(lro, input.shape, output.shape = NULL, initializer, mx.cpu())$arg.params
rand_pred <- predict(model, test.x)
plot(rand_pred,trained_pred)
```

---

Edit: A similar approach is possible with R's neuralnet package.  I wrote the following to investigate different starting weights in [r neuralnet forcing overfitting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302732/r-neuralnet-forcing-overfitting/302754#302754)

```
nn<-neuralnet( .... )

startweights<-nn$weights
for (i in 1:length(startweights[[1]])) {      
  # trick to get right shape matrix
  startweights[[1]][[i]] <- startweights[[1]][[i]]*0 + runif(n=length(wts),min=-2,max=+2)
}

nn$weights <- startweights
```

Comment: This answer is only code. If you think this is the real answer to this Q (I don't have any expertise here), we should migrate this thread to [SO]. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Thank you **P.Windridge**. Do I read it correctly that after loading this *function* into my environment, I will get **params** <- mx.model.init.params(rnn.sym, input.shapes, initializer, ctx). Where: return(list(arg.params=arg.params, aux.params=aux.params)). Can I then use these params to run **predict**? BTW, I am sorry if I posted this question in the wrong place.

Comment: The only way I would expand the answer is to add an explicit example, i.e. it would remain only code.  On that basis feel free to migrate.

Comment: @AlexBurn, you can use it in several ways.  I have added an example.  Note, you don't need to load anything extra apart from mxnet (mx.model.init.params is part of the package)

Comment: Thank you a lot P.Windridge. I am trying this code. I will let know later how I managed to understand it.

Comment: I guess my version of mxnet for R is already outdated. I cannot run mx.model.init.params due to error: **Error in is.MXSymbol(symbol) : could not find function "is.MXSymbol"**. I will try the latest version then. Meanwhile I think I understand pretty much everything from your code. I have never though it would be possible: **model$arg.params <- mx.model.init.params**. Looks nice.

Comment: I run it. I see that arg.params change randomly. This is completed. ) Thank you again.

Comment: @P.Windridge, I forgot to accept your answer. I am doing good with that solution, thanks again.